# Mistake with deep linking

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to use a deep link for my app.

I set that in the XML :

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsite.fr/test"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I wanted to try this, with adb like that :

```
am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.mywebsite.fr/app" fr.myapp
```

But I've this error :

> Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent

What is the problem ? Probably I missed something...

Answer (score 0):

To test this I use an adb command which also is able to handle request parameters:

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://www.mywebsite.fr/app?someparameter=somevalue"'
```

And it depends what you have defined in your manifest, so that the app can understand your URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I understood my problem, see my post :)

Comment: I saw it - after my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as always, it's when I create a post I see the problem :D

The host was bad I need to change the host, I've added the full URL whereas I need to just set "www.mywebsite.fr/" in android:host, and android:pathPrefix="/test"